# Gazan attitudes to Egyptian rule 1948-1967

Tags: 20th-century, egypt

Was Egyptian rule viewed favourably by the population? Were there uprisings?

Another related question: were there travel restrictions of some form (*i.e.* could Gazans travel freely in Egypt)?

UPDT: Nothing? No information anywhere?...:( 
Here's a specific subquestion: were there any kind of opinion polls held then in Gaza? (probably not, but perhaps on the off-chance)

Comment: @Sardathrion: The second one is more like a subquestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some info on travel restrictions in a very specific period.

During the 1948–1959 [All-Palestine Government Period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_occupation_of_the_Gaza_Strip#All-Palestine_Government_.281948.E2.80.931959.29) (a puppet state of Egypt controlling Gaza) 14,000 All-Palestine passports were [issued](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3atLWuwq3-EzYJ%3awww.palestine-studies.org/enakba/diplomacy/Shlaim,%2520The%2520Rise%2520and%2520Fall%2520of%2520the%2520All%2520Palestine%2520Govt.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjTCxg-Mc8Abwy0YCcW2WDoYRhLmUdZfHUMhCYoeln3sLP0N5FMqh7DCpoGd8a3rUP3Wq_3CPyLAA9ebM4lCy3MYovvpD7ew_glCzzO9DkRk4Ux6c0DUFJfbQWoB_qh_KfOtLvU&sig=AHIEtbS3eM_OY9oW_y8NQtpYIOw0iU64sg), mostly to Gazan notables and businessmen, with any Palestinians being eligible (including residents of the Jordanian controlled West Bank). It's hard to say what percentage of the [population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza#Population) this was. 1945 figures show 32,250, but this was before the [Nakba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Palestinian_exodus) and the next figure is 100,272 in 1982.

Ahmed Mu-awad, writing in *Sarakha Illah al-Sama* [*Cry to Heaven*] states:

*"Among the tens of passports that I checked, I foud many with entrance permits to Egypt, and a few with Saudi Arabian permits"*

This suggests that entrance to Egypt did not come with this passport, but was often granted by the Egyptian government. The book goes onto state that the passport was not recognised elsewhere. So it would seem that the main function of this passport was admittance to Egypt.

Comment: I'll see what more I can get on the Palestinian Legislative Council Period later, I imagine it would be a similar situation. Shame no-ones got anything on the main question, it's a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, finally we are making some progress on this!

Comment: The PLO during the period (formed 1964) in question supported the Egyptian version of 'Pan-Arabism'. [Here's a link to their original charter](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Peace/cove1.html) (The agenda of the website is not important here). So the PLO were in bed with Egypt, so a useful question would be: were the PLO popular in Gaza before the Six Day War?

Comment: I also understand the [Arab Nationalist Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Nationalist_Movement) was the dominant party in Palestine before the Six Day War when it lost ground to Fatah. This party was also a fan "Pan-Arabism" and apparently close to [Nasserist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasserism) factions. To conclude my guess (emphasis on guess) is Gazans were quite pro-Egypt.

Comment: But now you got me confused - why did Nasser switch his support to the PLO? Did he come to the conclusion that ANM was ineffectual?

Comment: The PLO is like a government. It's always been a coalition of Palestinian parties, before 1967 it was dominated by the ANM and after by Fatah.